# angular2: strange null error from an injected service

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have a very basic web app which has a `Home component` that uses a `localStorage` service to check if a local ip has been set.  If the local ip hasn't been set it must navigate to the settings page where a local IP can be entered.  When I run my app (using ng-cli) I get the following error.  It seems like even though I injected `localStorageService` in the `constructor` it's `null` for some reason...  Any idea what might be going wrong?

my `error`:

```
main.bundle.js:42342
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'localIP'
of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'localIP' of null
    at LocalStorageService.getLocalIP (
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64378:18)
    at HomeComponent.ngOnInit (
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64008:46)
    at Wrapper_HomeComponent.detectChangesInInputProps (/AppModule/HomeComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:18:53)
    at _View_HomeComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/HomeComponent/host.ngfactory.js:30:27)
    at _View_HomeComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:59869:14)
    at _View_HomeComponent_Host0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:59974:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:43438:20)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:46946:42)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:15157:16)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:15135:22)
```

my `HomeComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private restService: RestService, private localStorageService: LocalStorageService, private router: Router) {
this.localStorageService = new LocalStorageService();     
}

  ngOnInit() {    
      let ip = this.localStorageService.getLocalIP();
      if (!ip.length > 0) {
          this.router.navigate(['settings']);
      }
      console.log(this.localStorageService.getLocalIP());  


  }

}
```

my `LocalStorageService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {

saveLocalIP(ip: string): void {
    let localData = localStorage.getItem('retail_mobile');
    if (localData) {
        localData = JSON.parse(localData);
    } else {
        localData = "";
    }

    localData = "{localIP:" + ip + "}";
    localStorage.setItem('retail_mobile', JSON.stringify(localData));   
}

getLocalIP() {
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('retail_mobile'));
    if (!data.localIP) {        
        console.log("No local IP found in local storage...");
        return '';
    }

    return data.localIP;
}

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: remove `this.localStorageService = new LocalStorageService();     `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in *getLocalIP()* function.

```
getLocalIP() {
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('retail_mobile'));
    ................
    ................
}
```

You are getting data as *null*. So put one more extra check and validate data against null.

```
if (data && !data.localIP)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankush Jain that didn't get rid of the error either...  It seems like the localService instance is null for some reason...

Comment: thanks.  When I added a check for null in the getLocalIP function it worked/got rid of the error...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant to use just

```
localData = {localIP: ip };
```

in `saveLocalIP`

Answer (score 0):

No need to create new instance of services remove `this.localStorageService = new LocalStorageService();`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private restService: RestService, private localStorageService: LocalStorageService, private router: Router) {

}

  ngOnInit() {    
      let ip = this.localStorageService.getLocalIP();
      if (!ip.length > 0) {
          this.router.navigate(['settings']);
      }
      console.log(this.localStorageService.getLocalIP());  


  }

}
```

Comment: I added that after just to make sure that localService can't be null...  Removing it doesn't seem to change anything, still getting the same error.

Comment: have you added your `LocalStorageService` in module.ts